# AVR JTAGICE mkII

Tags: avr, jtag, atmel

Original Atmel jtag programmer costs $300.

http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card_v2.asp?tool_id=3353

http://search.digikey.com/scripts/DkSearch/dksus.dll?site=us&lang=en&mpart=ATJTAGICE2

Which clone do you recommend me?
Are they 100% clones? (work with avr studio, same fw etc.)

thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You should get the AVR Dragon.  It has ISP, JTAG, DebugWire and HV programming capabilities, fully powered by USB, and costs around $60.

http://www.atmel.com/dyn/products/tools_card.asp?tool_id=3891

Comment: Just got one from digikey the other day, works flawlessly with avrdude. :)

Comment: I have read that the dragon is a little prone to breakage, has anyone experienced problems?

Comment: I finally managed to kill one when I plugged in the ISP header backwards and must have sent +5V into something that wasn't expecting it (cue: blue smoke), but aside from that it's held up quite well to short-circuits on the +5V line and general physical abuse.

Answer (score 0):

The JTAG MKIIs are not indestructible. I have 6 JTAG MKIIs. Two of them have failed, one was at least 3-4 years old. The second was 2 months old. Over the years I have also had 8-10 flat flex cables fail and a pod fail. The most recently purchased came with an extra flat flex cable.

I purchased a Chinese knockoff, it never worked.

I have a Dragon I don't use.

I would like to buy 1-2 of http://www.dhgate.com/usb-avr-jtag-ice-mk-ii-metal-box-anodised/r-ff8080812cf9abc5012cfaf3e60f6e35.html I like the metal enclosure and the fact that it uses a ribbon cable instead of the flat flex cable, but I am gun shy since the other knockoff was DOA.

I keep purchasing the real unit and have recommended on several occasions that clients do the same.

Answer (score -1):

[This](http://shop.embedded-projects.net/index.php?module=artikel&action=artikel&id=33) might suit your needs and costs only 40 Euros. Or you could build your own with some instructions from [here](http://www.scienceprog.com/build-your-own-avr-jtagice-clone/).

Comment: The first link is dead.